# How to create watermark like shutterstock with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to create image watermark like Shutterstock. I have tried but not able to replicate it. I tried with the following command. The issue is for me is i not able to add diagonal random text to image as Shutterstock does. I have tried many options with no luck.

```
infile="zoom.jpg"
ww=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:w-1]" info:)
hh=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:h-1]" info:)
convert "$infile" \
-fill "graya(100%,0.75)" \
-draw "line 0,0 $ww,$hh line $ww,0 0,$hh" -alpha off \
-fill "graya(50%,0.25)" \
tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg

composite -dissolve 35 -gravity center logo.png tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg

convert -background none -size 220x320 xc:none  -font DejaVu-Sans-Bold -pointsize 30 \
-gravity  North -draw "rotate -22 fill grey text 20,10 'knot9'"   \
-gravity  West -draw "rotate -27 fill grey text 5,15 '89898989'"   \
miff:- |\
composite -dissolve 70 -tile - tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg  tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg

width=`identify -format %w tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg`; \

convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x30 -pointsize 10 -font DejaVu-Sans-Bold\
          caption:"\nThis image is Copyrighted by Knot9 \n www.knot9.com | Image Id: 89898989\n" \
          tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg +swap -gravity south -composite  tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg
```

**My Output is** [image]

**Requirement is** 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In ImageMagick, you can do the following. Create a small text image on a transparent background using label:. Rotate it. Pad it to control the spacing. Tile it out to fill the image. Then composite the tiled out image over your background image.

Image:

[image]

```
convert lena.png \
\( -size 100x -background none -fill white -gravity center \
label:"watermark" -trim -rotate -30 \
-bordercolor none -border 10 \
-write mpr:wm +delete \
+clone -fill mpr:wm  -draw 'color 0,0 reset' \) \
-compose over -composite \
lena_watermark.png
```

[image]

If using ImageMagick 7, then change convert to magick

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile_memory for tiling

Comment: I get a warning```convert: geometry does not contain image `watermark' @ warning/attribute.c/GetImageBoundingBox/519.```

Comment: What is your IM version and platform/OS? Did you use my command properly? What was your exact command?  Did you keep the new lines after each \ just like in my command?  If you are on Windows, then the syntax is slightly different.