# How to create watermark like shutterstock and Adobe Stock in python

Tags: python, dataset, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to create a GAN model which will remove watermark. After doing some homework, I got to this [Google AI](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-visible-watermarks-more-effective.html) Blog which makes things worse. Thus I need to create a dataset from these websites ***Shutterstock, Adobe Stock, Fotolia and Canstock*** and manymore.

So, when I try to do same image using **reverse image search**. I founded out that the resolutions, images are changed which makes it more worse.

Thus, I'm only left to create a custom dataset doing the same watermark like from these websites and that's why I need to create same watermark like them on images from unsplash and so..

Can anyone please help me create same watermark which we can get from **Shutterstock and Adobe Stock**. It'd be a great help.

**Note:** I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101441/how-to-create-watermark-like-shutterstock-with-imagemagick) for watermark using Imagemagick but I need it in python. If someone can show me a way of doing the same in python. That'd be a great help.

**EDIT1:** If you look at this [Example of Shutterstock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9IFR.jpg). Zoom in and you will find that not only lines but text and rounded symbols are curved and also name and rounded symbol with different opacity. So, that's what I want to replicate.

Comment: You could use Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Create an image of the text
- Rotate the text image
- Tile out the rotated text image to the size of the input
- Blend the tiled, rotated text image with the input image
- Save the output

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

text = "WATERMARK"
thickness = 2
scale = 0.75
pad = 5
angle = -45
blend = 0.25

   def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # function to rotate an image
    # from https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

# read image
photo = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
ph, pw = photo.shape[:2]

# determine size for text image
(wd, ht), baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, thickness)
print (wd, ht, baseLine)

# add text to black background image padded all around
pad2 = 2 * pad
text_img = np.zeros((ht+pad2,wd+pad2,3), dtype=np.uint8)
text_img = cv2.putText(text_img, text, (pad,ht+pad), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, (255,255,255), thickness)

# rotate text image
text_rot = rotate_bound(text_img, angle)
th, tw = text_rot.shape[:2]

# tile the rotated text image to the size of the input
xrepeats = math.ceil(pw/tw)
yrepeats = math.ceil(ph/th)
print(yrepeats,xrepeats)
tiled_text = np.tile(text_rot, (yrepeats,xrepeats,1))[0:ph, 0:pw]

# combine the text with the image
result = cv2.addWeighted(photo, 1, tiled_text, blend, 0)

# save results
cv2.imwrite("text_img.png", text_img)
cv2.imwrite("text_img_rot.png", text_rot)
cv2.imwrite("lena_tiled_rotated_text_img.jpg", result)

# show the results
cv2.imshow("text_img", text_img)
cv2.imshow("text_rot", text_rot)
cv2.imshow("tiled_text", tiled_text)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Text Image:

[image]

Rotated Text Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm thankful for your solution but if you zoom in any image from Shutterstock or so. They have curve lines with different opacity. So, can you please help me with that too...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation in Python/OpenCV that does outline font for the watermark. I have made the font size larger so that the outline is more visible.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

text = "WATERMARK"
thickness = 2
scale = 1.5
pad = 5
angle = -45
blend = 0.4

# function to rotate an image
def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # from https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

# read image
photo = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
ph, pw = photo.shape[:2]

# determine size for text image
(wd, ht), baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, thickness)
print (wd, ht, baseLine)

# add text to black background image padded all around
# write thicker white text and then write over that with thinner gray text to make outline text
pad2 = 2 * pad
text_img = np.zeros((ht+pad2,wd+pad2,3), dtype=np.uint8)
text_img = cv2.putText(text_img, text, (pad,ht+pad), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, (256,256,256), thickness+3)
text_img = cv2.putText(text_img, text, (pad,ht+pad), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, (128,128,128), thickness)

# rotate text image
text_rot = rotate_bound(text_img, angle)
th, tw = text_rot.shape[:2]

# tile the rotated text image to the size of the input
xrepeats = math.ceil(pw/tw)
yrepeats = math.ceil(ph/th)
print(yrepeats,xrepeats)
tiled_text = np.tile(text_rot, (yrepeats,xrepeats,1))[0:ph, 0:pw]

# combine the text with the image
#result = cv2.addWeighted(photo, 1, tiled_text, blend, 0)
mask = blend * cv2.threshold(tiled_text, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
result = (mask * tiled_text.astype(np.float64) + (255-mask)*photo.astype(np.float64))/255
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite("text_img.png", text_img)
cv2.imwrite("text_img_rot.png", text_rot)
cv2.imwrite("lena_tiled_rotated_text_img2.jpg", result)

# show the results
cv2.imshow("text_img", text_img)
cv2.imshow("text_rot", text_rot)
cv2.imshow("tiled_text", tiled_text)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it's different. Can you please take a look at the example in the question about the curve lines and other stuffs.

Comment: I looked on Shutterstock and the examples are like what I posted. If you have some other example in mind, please post it.  I do not know how to change the font family in OpenCV.

Comment: I have added an example in question. If you zoom in then you'll find it our that the lines, text and rounded squares are curved and of different opacity.

Comment: I have shown you how to do outline text. You can reverse the colors so that the white is inside and the dark is outside, if you want. As I said, I do not know how to change the font family to make other style text so that it is more rounded. OpenCV seems to only have one style.

Comment: Oh... Okay. Anyways, thanks for your solution. That's big help in itself.